# .htaccess double redirection

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, double

I'm really new to url rewriting and totally suck with regex, so sorry if my question is dumb (as i don't fully understand the subject)

here are my rewrite rules

```
RewriteRule ^trends/conversion/([_a-zA-Z0-9-]*) trends/conversion.php?$1

RewriteRule ^trends/([_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)$ trends/index.php?$1
```

Basically, I always end up to the index.php page, unless I remove the second rule, of course. Can i make the mod rewrite stop as soon as it reaches conversion.php?

Thanks in advance

Fabio

p.s. i forgot to say that i need to target the query string of both pages, that's why there is a regexp on the second one too. Unfortunately, I can't change this url structure, that's why I'm stuck

Answer (score 1):

You must first add a `L` flag to your first rule and add a `RewriteCond` to your second to prevent `conversion.php` being rewritten again

```
RewriteRule ^trends/conversion/([_a-zA-Z0-9-]*) trends/conversion.php?$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !conversion\.php
RewriteRule ^trends/([_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)$ trends/index.php?$1 [L]
```

You should consider changing the query string to something like `id=$1` or similar. Otherwise, you don't have the same `GET` parameter on every request, but an arbitrary string.

Comment: Thanks! The following way also works:


    RewriteRule ^trends/conversion/([_a-zA-Z0-9-]*) trends/conversion.php?$1 [QSA]

    RewriteRule ^trends/([_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)$ trends/index.php?$1 [QSA]